# How to sort bootstrap datatable datewise?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatable

I am using bootstrap datatable to display data in my project. i fetch data using 'data-url' attribute and then deisplay it in table. following is my table code.

```
<table id="user-table"  
             data-url="<?= Url::base().'/index.php/site/list-users';?>"
             data-toggle="table"
             data-toolbar="#user-delete-row"
             data-search="true"
             data-show-refresh="true"
             data-show-toggle="true"
             data-show-columns="true"
             data-sort-name="registrationDate"
             data-sort-order="desc"
             data-page-list="[5, 10, 20, 50, All]"
             data-page-size="5"
             data-pagination="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" class="table-bordered ">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
              <th data-field="registrationDate" data-sortable="true">Registration Date</th>
              <th data-field="full_name" data-sortable="true">Full Name</th>
              <th data-field="email" data-sortable="true">Email Address</th>
              <th data-field="phone" data-sortable="true" data-formatter="dateFormatter">Phone Number</th>
              <th data-field="department" data-sortable="true">Department</th>
              <th data-field="user_type" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Type of User</th>
              <th data-field="action" data-align="center" data-formatter="actionFormatter" data-events="operateEvents" data-sortable="true" data-sorter="priceSorter">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

        </table>
```

i want to sort data on basis of 'registration date'. it works fine if i sort it on basis of 'id' however i don't want to display integer id, so, i want to sort it on 'registrationDate' but it not working. i tried sorting following three dates in decending. 
 '24/06/2016 09:25',
 '23/06/2016 09:29',
 '05/07/2016 08:34',

but data-sort attribute is not working fine for sorting date. it sort's data on basis of day only and does not take month and year into account.
how to sort it on data basis?

Answer (score 1):

[Use this link for datatable](https://datatables.net/)
this is best datatable for php

You get data in mysql with ascending and descending order by Registration Date

```
    $("#example1").dataTable(
    {
        "order": [],
    } );
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion kuldeep but i need some solution for datatable which i am using as it has some other features integrated in my theme and i have to use this datatable only.

Comment: You get data in mysql with ascending and descending order by Registration Date and set data-sortable='false' or default  mode.....